# How to modify dijkstra to calculate minimum maximum bottleneck route?

Tags: python, algorithm, dijkstra, weighted-graph

This is the dijkstra I have right now coded with Python, but I don't know how I should modify this to calculate the route with the smallest possible max weight.

```
def dijkstra(g,s):
    
    for i in g.vertices:
        g.dist[i] = INF
        g.pred[i] = 0
        
    g.dist[s] = 0
    
    queue = [i for i in g.vertices]
    
    while len(queue) > 0:
        minval = INF
        u = 0
        for vert in queue:
            if g.dist[vert] < minval:
                minval = g.dist[vert]
                u = vert
        queue.remove(u)         
        
        for edge in g.adj_list[u]:
            v = edge.node
            if g.dist[v] > g.dist[u] + edge.weight:
                g.dist[v] = g.dist[u] + edge.weight
                g.pred[v] = u
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot make sure maximum bottleneck route，I guess it is a path from S to T and the minimum edge on it is maximum. If this, I do not think we can set a queue keeping the montonicity (I feel it is the nature of diji). Maybe you can only use Binary Search with bfs?

Answer (score 0):

if i don't mistake you ,try it,S is 1,T is 5

```
5 5
1 2 12
1 3 11
2 4 9
3 4 11
4 5 11
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the working algorithm to find the min max bottleneck route:

```py
def dijkstra(g,s):
    
    for i in g.vertices:
        g.dist[i] = INF
        g.pred[i] = 0
        
    g.dist[s] = 0
    
    queue = [i for i in g.vertices]
    
    while len(queue) > 0:
        minval = INF
        u = 0
        for vert in queue:
            if g.dist[vert] < minval:
                minval = g.dist[vert]
                u = vert
        queue.remove(u)         
        
        for edge in g.adj_list[u]:
            v = edge.node
            if g.dist[v] > max(g.dist[u], edge.weight):
                g.dist[v] = max(g.dist[u], edge.weight)
                g.pred[v] = u
```

as per OP @niaragua's edit to the question.